# Get int from String, also containing letters, in Java

Tags: java, integer

How can I get the int value from a string such as `423e` - i.e. a string that contains a number but also maybe a letter?

`Integer.parseInt()` fails since the string must be entirely a number.

Comment: not knowing anything about java, I know you could do this with regex. first strip out all the characters that aren't 0-9, then parseInt whatever is left. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Replace all non-digit with blank: the remaining string contains only digits.

```
Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
```

This will also remove non-digits inbetween digits, so `"x1x1x"` becomes `11`.

If you need to confirm that the string consists of a sequence of digits (at least one) possibly followed a letter, then use this:

```
s.matches("[\\d]+[A-Za-z]?")
```

Answer (score 22):

The NumberFormat class will only parse the string until it reaches a non-parseable character:

```
((Number)NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("123e")).intValue()
```

will hence return 123.

Comment: There is also [getIntegerInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getIntegerInstance%28%29)

Answer (score 10):

Unless you're talking about base 16 numbers (for which there's a method to parse as Hex), you need to explicitly separate out the part that you are interested in, and then convert it. After all, what would be the semantics of something like 23e44e11d in base 10?

Regular expressions could do the trick if you know for sure that you only have one number. Java has a built in regular expression parser.

If, on the other hands, your goal is to concatenate all the digits and dump the alphas, then that is fairly straightforward to do by iterating character by character to build a string with StringBuilder, and then parsing that one.

Comment: Thanks, I did it using regex. I thought there might be a built-in method somewhere though.

Answer (score 6):

Just go through the string, building up an int as usual, but ignore non-number characters:

```
int res = 0;
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c < '0' || c > '9') continue;
    res = res * 10 + (c - '0');
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that last line should be `res = res * 10 + c - '0';`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use Scanner :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(MyString);
s.nextInt();
```

Comment: The [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class assumes whitespace as the delimiter between the tokens, but that can be changed to any regex like in `new Scanner("456e").useDelimiter("\\D").nextInt()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps get the size of the string and loop through each character and call isDigit() on each character.  If it is a digit, then add it to a string that only collects the numbers before calling Integer.parseInt().

Something like:

```
    String something = "423e";
    int length = something.length();
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Character character = something.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
            result += character;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("result is: " + result);
```

Comment: The algorithm is correct, but you should use StringBuilder to append to result.

Comment: Agreed.  I guess one can't always be perfect when typing in haste.

Comment: Better not be so hasty then. Concatenation in a cycle is one of the worst things you could possibly do with strings. And it is still not fixed after 6 years.

Comment: If only there was an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2338814/edit) link....