# Grabbing ints from a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

Let's say I have a string "-1 2"
Is there a "reverse string.format" where I can grab those ints like

```
Integer first = new Integer();
Integer second = new Integer();
String.grab("%d %d", first, second);
print(first + " " second); // prints "-1 2"
```

Comment: Do you need to support all kings of whitespace? Or is your input one space delimited only

Comment: If the digits are delimited by a `space` , you could use scanners woth space as deliiter and use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the extracted digit(string) to `integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your input by spaces, then call Integer.parseInt on each string:

```
String input = "-1 2 -4 6 8";
String[] numberStringArray = input.split(" ");

for (String s : numberStringArray) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println("n = " + n);
}
```

***NOTE***: this does ZERO error checking

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Though I've never actually seen it used outside of homework.

Comment: +1 for never seen it used in anger... because it (IMHO) basically sucks.

Comment: A code example showing how to use it in this case would help this answer.

Comment: @Paul: He seemed like a bright young man who only needs to be nudged in the right direction.  I don't actually recommend using `Scanner`, but without more information it's hard to say what the best solution would be.

Comment: And... since Scanners are for students, let them enjoy the valuable experience of learning!

Answer (score 2):

Are the `int`s in the String always going to be formatted the same way? If so, why not use split()?

```
String input = "-1 21"
String[] stringArray = input.split(" ");
```

Then just print out each element in the array.

```
String printedString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    printedString += stringArray[i] + " ";
{

System.out.println(printedString);
```

Optimize for your needs.

Comment: I was going to post something like this, but I was waiting to find out if he had more than one kind of whitespace ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `Integer.parseInt()`

Replace all non-digit with blank: the remaining string contains only digits.

```
Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
```

This will also remove non-digits inbetween digits, so `"x1x1x"` becomes `11`.

If you need to confirm that the string consists of a sequence of digits (at least one) possibly followed a letter, then use this:

```
s.matches("[\\d]+[A-Za-z]?")
```

Refer this question in stackoverflow - [get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java)

Comment: This won't get separate numbers. You want `2 1 3` to return 3 `Integer` objects, not the number `213`

Comment: So are we processing digits interspersed with whitespace "noise" (i.e. dodgy input), or space-seperated numbers?... My spidey senses tell me it's the later... just because it's more logical.

Comment: @durron597 u can use `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` only returns 1 `int`. He has a string of text with more than 1 `int`