# change text color based on value of text

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to figure out how to change the color of TextView based on the value of the text.
TextView has been sent from another activity I have that part working fine. What I want is a way to change the color of the text based on what is in the TextView. So if previous Activity sends a value like "11 Mbps" as TextView then I would like that text color to be yellow, "38 Mbps" green, and 1 Mbps red.  I'm using eclipse if that helps at all.

This is how I'm sending the TextView to another activity. "showmsg" is just username sent to another page.

```
buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){
            final TextView username =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
            String uname = username.getText().toString();

            final TextView wifistrength =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Speed);
            String data = wifistrength.getText().toString();



                startActivity(new Intent(CheckWiFiActivity.this,DashboardActivity.class).putExtra("wifi",(CharSequence)data).putExtra("usr",(CharSequence)uname));


        }
    });
```

And this is how I receive it in the other activity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
               if (i.getCharSequenceExtra("wifi") != null) {
                final TextView setmsg2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Speed);
                setmsg2.setText(in.getCharSequenceExtra("wifi"));               
               }
```

This all works fine but I don't have a clue how to change the color of TextView based of the value of the text. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obviously want to set the color according to the number in the `String` you received from the previous Activity. So you need to parse it out of the `String`, save it to an `int` and then according to what the number is, set the color of your `TextView`.

```
String s = in.getCharSequenceExtra("wifi");
// the next line parses the number out of the string
int speed = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
setmsg2.setText(s);
// set the thresholds to your liking
if (speed <= 1) {
    setmsg2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else if (speed <= 11) {
    setmsg2.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
else {
    setmsg2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Please notice that this is an untested code, it might contain some mistakes.

The way to parse it comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2338819/1274911).

Comment: +1, I haven't tested it either but it looks like it would work. I started posting and almost didn't when I saw yours but I like using a `switch` when possible and just one line to call the function (here `setText()`. Good answer

Comment: This what exactly what I was looking for. I just copied and pasted BUT i will breakdown every part of this code to learn more about programming and eventually expand on it. I've only been doing this for a couple of months, but thanks to helpful programmers like yourself I am making a lot of progress. Thank you very much for helping with this.

Answer (score 1):

First, get all of the non-numeric characters out of your `String` and convert it to an `integer`. Then use a `switch` on the new value and set the color accordingly

```
String color = "blue";   // this could be null or any other value but I don't like initializing to null if I don't have to
int speed = i.getCharSequenceExtra("wifi").replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");    // remove all non-digits here
switch (speed)
{
    case (11):
        color = "yellow";
        break;
    case (38):
        color = "green";
        break;
    case(1):
        color = "red";
        break;
}
setmsg2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color);
```

[Here is a little site with some handy information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

[Color Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html_)

Comment: This answer was very helpful too, but I cant vote up because I don't have enough rep. Thanks for the links too.

Comment: Well, the problem with the `switch` statement here is that it only handles when the speed is exactly 1, 11 or 38. If it's something else, then the text will stay blue. But maybe the value can't be something else in his case, who knows. Just saying that it doesn't do the same thing as my code.