# Get negative int from String, also containing letters, in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've found something which almost fit my needs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java)

```
Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
```

but I can't find out how should I modify this to get negative integer. Sample string is:

```
"some\\-2c.st"
```

and I need to extract "-2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^\\d-]", ""))
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. This is what I need.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it the other way around, look for the integer instead of stripping the rest:

```
String str = "some\\-2c.st";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything you don't want, or you can extract that what you want.
It seems, the latter is more appropriate here, you can use a regex like `(-?\d+)` to do it.