# Comparing arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scoresedit {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Reads in a file at the beginning of a loop, displays these top 3 scores by name and their respective score." +
        "\nEnter a new name and score following a prompt. " +
        "\nIf the new name and score exceeds one of the top three scores," +
        "\nplaces the new name in the top three, moving all lower scores down, dropping the lowest score." +
        "\nSaves the results in the file top3Scores.txt."  +
        "\nStops the loop when exit is entered for a name.");
    File r = new File ("top3Scores.txt");
    System.out.println(r);
    String str = readSource (r);
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] strArray = new String[] {str};
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a new name and score or 'exit' to quit:");
    String nameAndScore = in.nextLine();
    String[] nameAndScoreArray = new String[] {nameAndScore};
    String nameAndScoreArray1[] =  nameAndScore.split(" ");
    while (nameAndScore != "exit") {
        if (nameAndScoreArray[1] > strArray[1]) }
    }

private static String readSource(File r) throws Exception{
    Scanner in;
    in = new Scanner (r);
    String str = "";
    while (in.hasNext())
        str += in.nextLine() +"\n";
    in.close();
    return str;
}

}
```

I keep getting the error "The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String" when I try to compare the two arrays and I don't know how to fix it. The code isn't finished; obviously I'm adding more under the if statement but I want to resolve this first.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to compare `nameAndScoreArray[1]` and `strArray[1]` which are strings, I assume they contain the scores of two teams and the one with the highest score wins, so you want to use `Integer.parseInt(String string)` in order to see which one has the highest score:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(nameAndScoreArray[1]) > Integer.parseInt(strArray[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I am trying to do something similar, the user inputs a name and score (ex: "John 5") and I am trying to compare the score entered with the the top score that is extracted from an external .txt file with three names and scores. I then will try to replace the top name score on the .txt file if the score inputed in higher.

Comment: @M.J.K. if your `String`s also contain letters and not just numbers then this wont work, you need to get rid of the non numerical value first. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java) question. You can edit your comments up to 5min after you've posted them btw, just click edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can not compare `String` with the operators `<`, `>`, instead you need to use [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thank you, the program asks the user to input a name and score (ex: "John 5") and I tried to split the string into an array so I could compare the score that the user entered with a list of scores extracted from an external .txt file, do you have any advice of how to do something like this? sorry I just read your the compareTo link you provided and still don't really understand

Comment: Then you need to make use of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17180327/122207