# Get Factorials using String value

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

i did up a class named "Factorial" using Recursion and it works perfectly, but this is when i input an integer value only. Code is below

```
import java.util.*;

public class Factorial {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int x, i;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Factorial");
    x=keyboard.nextInt();
    i = factorial(x);

    System.out.println(i);
}

  public static int factorial(int x)
  {
      int result;

         if(x==1)
           return 1;

         result = factorial(x-1) * x;
         return result;
  }

}
```

But now i want to tweak the code so that instead of accepting integer values, i would enter a String value like "4!" or "10!" or "100!" and the code would extract and convert the numerical values so that it would then be passed into the factorial class.
I was wondering if there is a fast way of doing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: ... doesn't it work exactly how you want it to right now? `keyboard.nextInt()` already reads the number up to a word break (end of the line or, in this case, a `'!'` character).

Comment: So are you talking about something like a calculator parser, because if you're not, what you're doing should work because you're using `nextInt()`

Comment: @Jashaszun if i entered 4!, the program would crash because of input mismatch - String entry is .nextLine(), and integer values are .nextInt(), you should know that if you had a string value, you'd get runtime exception

Comment: @user3ffgfgfgfgfg50064 yes, something like a calculator parser! i have serious mental block, i can't think of how to decode it

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Ah after reading the documentation I realized that `Scanner` splits the stream into tokens by whitespace. So you're right, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this link for some details: [Get int from String, also containing letters, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java)

On there, I found this answer:

> The NumberFormat class will only parse the string until it reaches a
>   non-parseable character:
>
> ```
> ((Number)NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("123e")).intValue()
> ```
>
> will hence return 123.

Get your input as a String, and use this to get the integer part of it.

Please let me know if you are having problems with it.

Comment: Dude this worked fine, i entered that line, then i had to import java.text.*, after that i added public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException and it Ran Fine, Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Scanner.nextLine()`, remove any `!`s, and then parse the resulting `String` as an `int`.

```
x = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine().replaceAll("!", ""));
```

instead of

```
x = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Alternatively, you could just write `keyboard.useDelimiter("!|\\n");` before your `x = keyboard.nextInt()` line and keep the latter line the same.