# Barcode Numbers too long for Integer.parseInt

Tags: android, json, zxing, parseint

im using zbar for barcode services, and at certain numbers the app shutsdown.

Im scanning barcodes, receive the barcode in an edittext, have it set up so it would search the json array for matching id's. Well this works fine for normal numbers the way that Integers extend to.. However i have a need to have it accept what ever value it contains.

Also when using breakpoints like `000.000.000.0` and `22-22ON` the app shuts down.

Does anyone have a clue on how to avoid this?

Is it possible to have it check for anything that is typed in?

Have looked at different snippets and tutorials, but cant find an answer..

```
     String xyz = edt.getText().toString();
            try {    // Getting JSON Array
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(xyz)-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(value) requires the String to only contain numbers.

If you look here the poster has a similar problem.
[Get int from String, also containing letters, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java)

Alternatively you could try simply using a String and try to match with that, if it is possible that the IDs like "22-22ON" are present in the database you're searching in.

Comment: My intention is to only have it result for values that are in the JSON array. Would it be possible to make it search for string values? When that value isnt there, im going to show a message, like 'product not found'.

Comment: It is definitely possible but if the array is large it might be slow to go through each element and checking String.equals.

If the JSONArray isnt containing several thousand elements it shouldnt be too much of a problem though. Just do something like for(JSONObject c : user) and then compare the value contained to xyz. If it matches, then you know it exists in the array, if not then its not there

Comment: do i compare the value with equals()?

Comment: It kind of depends on whats in your JSONArray, but maybe you could replace the JSONObject c with a String, and retrieve it in a for loop like `for(int i = 0; i<user.size(); i++){String c = user.getString(i); if(c.equals(xyz){ //do something }}`