# Java pick up JSON as value not as Integer

Tags: java, android, json

I wanted to know if anyone knows a way to pick up JSON Object as a value instead of an `Integer` or `Long`. Since i am trying to use a barcode application, alot of the codes contain Letters and breakpoints (like dots . and dashes -).

I got the json parsing working find, except it parses the value of the JSONObject I need as an Integer.

so, i can only use numbers and no whitespaces, dots or any other breaking points in that matter. But since the database contains numbers and numbers with letters like : `100.100.ab.100` and `100100100`, simple using `.replaceAll(".","")
.replaceAll("%20", "")` would just not cut it.

So the problem at hand is, can I convert a JSONObject which is received by URL and JSON parsing, to get it to accept any value entered?

I looked at the following post,

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464017/barcode-numbers-too-long-for-integer-parseint)

And i have tried to adapt my code accordingly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
    String c = user.getString(i);
    if (c.equals(xyz) {
    }
}
```

Another possible thought i had, was to use REGEX, or Regular Expressions to make the value searched for accept anything necessary, then again.. ***An Integer cannot accept anything besides numbers and it will crash and Burn.***

Answer (score 0):

You could add a header to your JSON data from where it is sent to force it to convert it to a String, then strip the header off. Provided you have access to the sender.

Alternatively, you could convert the number back to hexadecimal yourself, creating small "buckets" of numbers that make up the total. It's kind of hard to tell what exactly you are trying to do based on the information provided.

Comment: as header do you mean application/json??

Comment: I assume you're using some sort of conversion library that automatically turns the JSON into objects for you. The problem with this is that it automatically decides what datatype something needs based on the contents of the data. So by adding something that forces it to read your data as Strings like "STRINGENFORCER"+yournumberconvertiblehere in your sending application, it will read the whole line as a string instead of a number.