# How to parse an int from a string java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

I'm trying to parse an int from a dummy String for test reasons. The string will be:

```
String numOfStudents = "Number of Students: 5";
```

I want to parse this String, ensuring it contains the line 'Number of Students' as well as finding out the int value.

How can I achieve this? I need the int value to compare it to another int value.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get int from String, also containing letters, in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Integer cannot parse String values it throws `NumberFormatException` because numbers are expected as input, I would suggest you as you have static type of Strings use like this:

```
String numOfStudents = "Number of Students: 5";
String[] p = numOfStudents.split(":");

Integer i= Integer.parseInt(p[1].trim());
System.out.println(i);
```

As, `p[0]` contain String (label) and `p[1]` contain its value. You can use it later if you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
    final String NUM_OF_STUDENTS = "Number of Students: ";

    String numOfStudents = "Number of Students: 5";
    int lastIndex = numOfStudents.lastIndexOf(NUM_OF_STUDENTS);

    if (lastIndex != -1){
        String number = numOfStudents.substring((lastIndex + (NUM_OF_STUDENTS.length())) , numOfStudents.length());
        Integer yourResultNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
        System.out.println(yourResultNumber);
    }
```

Comment: Your code throws exceptions if String does not contain "Number of Students"

Comment: After copying the fix from my answer and downvoting it.

Comment: Well, your code did had an exception, I would thank you if you consider vote up my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String numOfStudents = "Number of Students: 55546";
int lastIndex = numOfStudents.lastIndexOf(" ");
if(lastIndex > -1 && lastIndex+1 < numOfStudents.length()) {
String num = numOfStudents.substring(lastIndex+1);
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(num));
}
```