# Get an Integer that can be modified from a String?

Tags: java, string-parsing

So, the full String that I'm trying to read is:

```
Members online: (0/0):
Members offline: (0/0):
```

While I think I could substring it to get the 0, it can change it's size, because it's an int... Is there any way I could get the integers even if they change?
Thanks.

EDIT: I also want to only get the first integer of "0/0"... Any ways I could do this? I know I could use regex but I don't know if it's the best way to do it...

Comment: Why dont you try it with regular expressions. just google it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get int from String, also containing letters, in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338790/get-int-from-string-also-containing-letters-in-java)

Comment: You should never use regex for task like this. Just get indexOf('(') and indexOf('/') and indexOf(')') and use Integer.parseInt with proper substring

Comment: @Jack, that depends on many factors, including the need for making sure the string has the expected format. I think my first shot would be a regex, then I might consider changing later if I encounter reasons for doing so.

Comment: Nah, @takendarkk, it’s hardly a strict duplicate. In that other question there is only one number in the string, and its format is not known.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.
I've solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **indexOf** and **lastIndexOf** for that purpose.

```
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(t.indexOf('(') + 1, t.indexOf('/')))
```

That variable (n1) will save the number itself, if you want just the position you should use next one.

```
int pos=t.indexOf('(') + 1
```

Comment: probably better to get the whole string between `(` and `/` as it might be more than a single digit.

Comment: @JohnM :  Please mark the response as an answer if it has worked for you